# Unable to use variable in view

Tags: php, model-view-controller, scope

I'm building my own MVC framework and have encountered a problem when sending variables into views. The `loadView()` looks like this:

```
function loadView($view, $variables = array())
{
    $file_path = APPLICATION_PATH . 'views/' . $view;

    if (file_exists($file_path))
    {
        if (is_readable($file_path))
        {
            if (! empty($variables)) extract($variables);
            include($file_path);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception('Could not read view from ' . $file_path);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception('Could not load view from ' . $file_path);
    }
}
```

It works just as expected. However, when I'm setting up a template view like this things get weird:

```
loadView('layout/header.php');
loadView($view);
loadView('layout/footer.php');
```

It's called like this (`$user` is an object):

```
$data['view'] = 'login/showUser.php';
$data['user'] = $user;
loadView('layout/template.php', $data);
```

The `$view` variable gets set in the template file and loads the correct view. However, the `$user` variable is unable to travel into the dynamically loaded view which only contains this code:

```
<p>User ID: <?php echo $user->id; ?></p>
```

I can do this in CodeIgniter and I find it a little weird since when the `$view` and `$user` variables are extracted in the first `loadView()` call to the template, they should be available to the next view which is simply included into the scope.

What did I overlook?

Comment: Could you post the User class code as well?

Comment: If you start out with premise "make something like CI", then you are already doing it wrong.

Comment: Never said I did which would also be pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each loadView() call has its own local scope, which are not shared between different invocations of loadView(). In CodeIgniter, this likely works because its view renderer stores the variables in some static storage. You need to pass all variables you need in each view explicitly, or you need to add static storage to loadView(), like this:

```
function loadView($view, $variables = array())
{
    static $static_vars = array();
    $static_vars = array_merge($static_vars, $variables);
    ...
    extract($static_vars); // instead of extract($variables);
    ...
```

Comment: I was aware of the function scopes but started out my programming career with doing code such as `$var = 1; include('file.php'); // contains: echo $var;`, and as far I recall this worked. It must be because the include is called inside the function, in this case. This was exactly what I was looking for, by the way. Thanks!

Comment: `include()` is not actually a function call, it is actually a statement and does not introduce a new local scope; however, inside the outer view, you're calling loadView() again, which DOES introduce a new scope.